# Excel Error on Application.OnKey Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I put this simple code into Visual Basic:

```
Sub HelloWorld()
MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub

Sub OnKeyDemo()
Application.OnKey "^+a","HelloWorld"
End Sub
```

When I press CTRL+SHIFT+A on the Workbook, I get the following error:
[image]

I enabled all macros on Excel and I did a Step Into procedure recommended by others on StackExchange. Neither have worked.

Thanks!

Comment: It works for me.  Where did you place the macros?

Comment: The error message suggests that you have it in a sheet module or the workbook module rather than a general code module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are getting this error because the `Application.OnKey` is not able to find the `HelloWorld` subroutine.**

Microsoft's documentation does not have clear information regarding where the procedure should reside, in the general module or worksheet/workbook module.

**I have tried and tested by adding this procedure in the workbook/worksheet and general module. It only works in the **General Module****

To add a general module:
Open the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R) and right-click on any item.
Then Select Insert->Module

****In the general module add the **`Sub HelloWorld()`** procedure and it will definitely work.****

### ***Very Important***

**Reverse the OnKey Statement as not doing this may cause unexpected results.**

For Doing this follow the below steps:

1. Go to the ***ThisWorkbook*** Code Pane
2. Above the code pane you will find two dropdowns, select Workbook in first and BeforeClose in the second.
3. In the added code for BeforeClose, write **`Application.OnKey "^+a"`**, note the lack of `,"HelloWorld"`.

Omitting the `,"HelloWorld"` is fine since the second parameter for the `Application.OnKey` procedure is optional.

What **`Application.OnKey "^+a"`** does is resets the previously assigned key binding to the `HelloWorld` procedure.

I hope that I have been of help.